# Auto assigning from one list to another

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, filter

I'm trying to set up a reservation for cars in my agency.  I would like to try to auto-assign these cars based on what is entered from another screen.  Once I find an available car, based on that criteria, I want to mark it as reserved (will be based on date needed).  Is there a way to auto assign from one SharePoint list to another? I'm still pretty new to SharePoint and I'm thinking that this might be above and beyond the scope of this application.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I believe this can be done in SharePoint, but a little more info would be helpful.  Since you're relatively new to SP (and many of us are), I don't know if you've already delved in the wonderful world of Workflows, but it seems like this could be right up your alley here.  Do you have SharePoint Designer? Also, what version of SP are you working with?  Are you working with any third-party solutions like Nintex Workflow, etc?

Comment: I have delved into workflows and currently, I'm actually using SharePoint Online.  It sounds like the user wants more of a fleet optimization.  You know, picking a car from the inventory based on year, last used, local or long distance travel, type of tires, type of car, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I envision what you're talking about:  Two lists - one for the cars, the other for the calendar.  CarAssign (or whatever variable you've got for the field in the CARS list) is a drop down choice field (yes/no).  Each criteria is also a drop down list with the choice options located therein. The calendar (list) refers to the car list.  The workflow would be set up along the lines of "If Criteria A = Whatever, and Criteria B = Whatever (...etc), set CarAssign = YES."  Setting workflow conditions may be tedious here, depending on how many variables you're working with, but if you "map out" everything right, you should be successful.  Have the workflow activate each time a new record is created (in the calendar list...that's where the reservations are, right?)
Another thing to consider here is using views to your advantage.  Mind you, it may feel a bit "clunky", but if it works for you, then it's a plus.  You could set custom views for each of the vehicle types (set view filters based on each car type's variable definitions).  Perhaps using this in tandem with a good workflow will get you where you want to go.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but what we're needing is a lot more in-depth (probably outside the realms of SharePoint).  We'd need to use algorithms and have several nested for loops to achieve what we're after.  Unfortunately, SharePoint Designer doesn't allow for that.  I appreciate your willingness to help, and workflows had crossed my mind at one point. :)